# how to integrate mysql as primary database and mongodb as secondary database

Tags: django

I am working on a Django project where I need to use both mysql/postgresql as well as mongoDB, one as primary and one as secondary database. How do I configure my db settings to use two databases?

I am able to use 1 database as postgresql or mongoDB, but not able to use both. I have provided the code below of what I have tried.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': os.environ.get("DB_HOST", DB_HOST),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', DB_PORT),
        'NAME': os.environ.get("DB_NAME", DB_NAME),
        'USER': os.environ.get("DB_USER", DB_USER),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD", DB_PASSWORD),
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to this. We would need to use a third party plugin called Django MongoDB Engine. 
Documentation: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html

````
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    },
    'mongo' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}```
````